# Can't share from 1 of my computers, both with Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, file-sharing, sharing

I have 2 computers running Ubuntu. They can both access shared documents. One of my computers can share folders, but the other one can't. They are both Ubuntu **14.04 LTS**.

I've been trying to find out some information about this, but haven't had any luck. Sorry if its been asked before.

[imgur of disabled sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdMN9.png)

Also if there is any thing helpful I can add to improve this question please let me know (and how).  I am unsure what to look for and how to debug this issue.